# for loop using break and continue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, break, continue

I'm writing a for loop that needs to push no more than three elements to the array 'bag,' and use 'break' to jump out of the loop when 'bag' is full with said three elements. So far my code passes three out of the four tests. The issue I'm encountering is that for the fourth test, which should be where the code 'breaks' and the loop stops running, that instead, a fourth element is getting pushed to my 'bag' array. If 'bag' isn't full I need to traverse 'dolls' until the last element.

I'm a total beginner and I've tried a couple different things, but I can' figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code I have is below.

```
function grabDoll(dolls){
  var bag=[];
  //coding here
  for (let i = 0; i < dolls.length; i++) {
    if (dolls[i] == 'Hello Kitty' || dolls[i] == 'Barbie doll') {
      bag.push(dolls[i])
    } else if (dolls[i] == '') {
      continue;
    } else if (bag.length - 1 === 2) {
      break;
    } else continue;
  }
  return bag;
}
```

Comment: Your length check should be **before** other other checks, since `else if` will only check later conditions if earlier ones didn't match. (And there's no reason to use `bag.length -1 === 2` rather than `bag.length === 3`. You also don't need `else continue`; the loop will continue without any `else` clause.)

Comment: unsure why you need a break when it can be done in the for loop code itself. `for (let i = 0; i < dolls.length && bag.length < 3; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code to this

```
function grabDoll(dolls){
  var bag=[];
  //coding here
  for (let i = 0; i < dolls.length; i++) {
    if(bag.length === 3) {
      break;
    } else if (dolls[i] == 'Hello Kitty' || dolls[i] == 'Barbie doll') {
      bag.push(dolls[i])
    }
  }
  return bag;
}
```

Your code will only check the `else if`'s if the `if` or `else if` that came before it results to false. I.e if `if (dolls[i] == 'Hello Kitty' || dolls[i] == 'Barbie doll')` resolve to true, your code won't check the `else if` related to that `if`.
Also, you don't need the command `continue` to continue the loop. When the loop reachs the end, it'll check the loop condition again, if it resolves to true, the loop run again, otherwise, the loop stops. So you don't need this part

```
} else if (dolls[i] == '') {
      continue;
```

nor this

```
else continue;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that explanation! As one of the conditions of the exercise I have to use ```continue``` in the code, which is why I included it in the ```else if ``` Really appreciate your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use below JS code. I have just added condition of bag array must be contain only 3 elements at start in if else statement.

```
    function grabDoll(dolls)
    {
      var bag=[];     
      for (let i = 0; i < dolls.length; i++) 
      {
         if(bag.length == 3)
         {
           break;
         }
         else if (dolls[i] == 'Hello Kitty' || dolls[i] == 'Barbie doll') 
         {
           bag.push(dolls[i]);
         }            
         else continue;
       }
      return bag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @T.J Crowder for his comment. Got it

```
function grabDoll(dolls){
  var bag=[];
  //coding here
  for (let i = 0; i < dolls.length; i++) {
    if (bag.length === 3) {
      break;
    } else if (dolls[i] == 'Hello Kitty' || dolls[i] == 'Barbie doll') {
      bag.push(dolls[i])
    } else if (dolls[i] == '') {
      continue;
    }     
    }
  return bag;
}
```